# Oracle Json object DISTINCT keep getting repeating columns

Tags: asp.net, json, oracle, .net-6.0

So i have a query and it need to return a JSON object but the DISTINCT doesn't work no matter what I try. I've been trying a series of other tests and no matter what the 'WBS' always shows up with 3 or more duplicated columns. Anyone got any ideas?

I am working in Asp.net 6 MVC

```
PROCEDURE GET_BASELINE_RPT (in_WBS_LEVEL_ID IN NUMBER, in_FISCAL_YEAR IN VARCHAR2, 
in_FISCAL_MONTH IN VARCHAR2, RET OUT CLOB) AS
BEGIN
WITH cte AS (
SELECT /*+MATERIALIZE*/ DISTINCT L.WBS_LEVEL_ID
    FROM
    WBS_LEVEL L
    )
SELECT
     JSON_ARRAYAGG (
        JSON_OBJECT (
            'WBS' VALUE L.WBS_LEVEL_NAME,
            'Title' VALUE W.DESCRIPTION,
            'Rev' VALUE B.REV_NUMBER,
            'ScopeStatus' VALUE W.STATUS,
            'BCP' VALUE CASE WHEN BC.FISCAL_YEAR = 0 THEN '' ELSE
            SUBSTR(BC.FISCAL_YEAR,3,2)||'-'||LPAD(BC.BCP_FISCAL_ID, 3, '0') END,
            'BCPApprovalDate' VALUE BC.APPROVAL_DATE,
            'Manager' VALUE P1.NICK_NAME,
            'ProjectControlManager' VALUE P2.NICK_NAME,
            'ProjectControlEngineer' VALUE P3.NICK_NAME,
            'FiscalYear' VALUE W.FISCAL_YEAR,
            'FiscalMonth' VALUE W.FISCAL_MONTH,
            'WBSNumber' VALUE L.WBS_LEVEL_ID
        )RETURNING CLOB)
        INTO RET
    FROM WBS_LEVEL L
    LEFT OUTER JOIN BASELINE_RPT B ON L.WBS_LEVEL_ID = B.WBS_LEVEL_ID
    JOIN BCP BC ON BC.BCP_ID = B.BCP_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN WBS_TREE_MOD W ON L.WBS_LEVEL_ID  = W.WBS_LEVEL_ID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_SITEPEOPLE P1 ON W.WBS_MANAGER_SNUMBER = P1.SNUMBER
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_SITEPEOPLE P2 ON W.PCM_SNUMBER = P2.SNUMBER
    LEFT OUTER JOIN VW_SITEPEOPLE P3 ON W.PCE_SNUMBER = P3.SNUMBER
    ORDER BY L.WBS_LEVEL_NAME, B.REV_NUMBER DESC;

END GET_BASELINE_RPT;
```

Comment: You `join` the table to 6 other tables, while `distinct` is applied to a single table. Generally it is an issue with join predicates when new tables multiply rows. But without sample data it's impossible to answer

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out I wasn't getting duplicates at all. There were differences in the data but there were so many columns that had the same data that I didn't notice the differences until another review. I will try to restart my query but to be honest I may just put in a filter in my C#.